# How to pass colors to Android library?

Tags: android, android-library

I am creating an android library and I want to know the best way to pass colors from the main app module to my library.

I have the below colors in my colors file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="textColor1">#848484</color>
    <color name="textColor2">#99848484</color>
    <color name="textColor3">#676767</color>
    <color name="textColor4">#e7e6e6</color>
</resources>
```

What I want to do is to enable the user of the library to pass values for these colors programmatically so I can use them in my library using the normal way:

In XML:

```
android:textColor="@color/textColor1"
```

or in Java:

```
setTextColor(ActivityCompat.getColor(context, R.color. textColor1));
```

Comment: A user could override these colors in his own colors.xml, and you'd get those values instead.  That's built in functionality in Android.

Comment: you can create function in library with parameter which fetches colors.

Comment: @GabeSechan I know that, but there is a way I can do that programmatically?

Comment: @Nik Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @SherifElNady Not and use it in xml like that.  You can't override the  color values at runtime.  You could programmatically set the colors on your views if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There are many way to create this functionality. Below is one of them:
In Libray create util class:

```
class Utility{
public static int myColor = 0;    
     public void setColor (@ColorInt int colorId){ // integer id 
         myColor = colorId;
     }

}
```

Use this `colorId` in anywhere in your library

for ex.

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompact.getColor(context, Utility.myColor);
```

Apply color from your project like:

```
Utility.setColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

Comment: But that way the variable (myColor) cannot be used in XML.

Comment: Yes you cannot use directly that variable in your xml but if you use **dataBinding** then you can use.

Answer (score 2):

The way resource merger works is that, if we set `tools:override="true"` attribute, then root-app's resources override the resources of the library (-ies).

I mean, in root App's `colors.xml` file, do something like:

```xml
<color name="myColor" tools:override="true">#AABBCC</color>
```

But we did not like to add said attribute for each resource, hence I created `colors_overrides.xml` file (beside my `colors.xml` file), and added said attribute to `resource` element directly, like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:override="true">
    <color name="myColor">#AABBCC</color>
</resources>
```